# CUDA Execution Configuration Syntax...How do you make the compiler recognize it?

Tags: cuda

Super simple program:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <iostream>

__global__ void kernal_function() 
{

}

int main(void) 
{
    kernal_function<<<1,1>>>();

    return 0;
}
```

Won't compile because the compiler doesn't know what the `<<<>>>` is (error: expected an expression and syntax error: '<').

How do I make the compiler understand what this (`<<<>>>`) is?

Comment: put the code you have shown in a file with `.cu` extension, and compile it with `nvcc`.  There won't be any errors.  If this is something you're seeing within visual studio, (for example red underline) that is an artifact of intellisense, not the actual compiler.  You can compile this code just fine in visual studio as well, with a proper CUDA project, CUDA install on VS, and filename extension.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio, so it turned out the key was to add a Cuda Code file (not just renaming a .cpp to .cu). Would have worked if I used nvcc outside of Visual Studio, but I didn't try that. If you make this an answer I can accept it. Otherwise Robin's is good too.

Comment: If you're comfortable with the answer feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triple angle brackets syntax `<<<...>>>` is specific to CUDA. It not part of C or C++ standard. It will be recognized by `nvcc`, but not by `gcc` or any other 'classic' compiler.

You can build a CUDA runtime program this way:

```
nvcc main.cu -o my-program
```

Comment: Is there a way to make Visual Studios understand this syntax? It's throwing an error at the moment

Comment: Yes. Installing the [Nsight Visual Studio Edition](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition-2020_1) plugins should achieve this.  


Ideally, please follow the [**step-by-step guide**](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html) to download and install all related CUDA tools/dependencies you will need to develop/debug CUDA software on a Windows machine.